# how to wait for Http request complete?

Tags: javascript, http, request, httprequest

I write javascript app "Blackjack" and I need use some api.
First I created a deck and request returns me deck id.

```js
            fetch('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/?deck_count=1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.deck_id);
                deckId = data.deck_id;
            });
```

And then I want to draw cards.

```js
           for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++)
           {
               for (let x = 0; x < players.length; x++)
                {
                    fetch('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/' + deckId + '/draw/?count=1')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log(data.remaining);
                        deckLenght = data.remaining;
                        data.cards.map((card)=>
                        {
                            var newCard = getCardData(card);
                            players[x].Hand.push(newCard);
                            renderCard(newCard, x);
                            updatePoints();
                            updateDeck();
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
```

But when I send this request my deck id is undefined.
How to fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your `for` loop into the `.then()` handler of the first HTTP request. That way it will be executed after your request finishes, not in parallel to it:

```
fetch('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/?deck_count=1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.deck_id);
    const deckId = data.deck_id;
    for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < players.length; x++) {
        fetch('https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/' + deckId + '/draw/?count=1')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
             console.log(data.remaining);
             const deckLength = data.remaining;
             data.cards.map((card) => {
               var newCard = getCardData(card);
               players[x].Hand.push(newCard);
               renderCard(newCard, x);
               updatePoints();
               updateDeck();
             });
           });
       }
     }
  });
```